# How to create a indicator that loops through date and unique client ID?

Tags: spss

The data structure is as follows:

```
Cli_ID   M_YR    trans-Date     First_Trans
1004525 Oct 17  30-Oct-17   20-Sep-17
1004570 Oct 17  02-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  05-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  10-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  11-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  12-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  13-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  17-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  19-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  23-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  24-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1004570 Oct 17  25-Oct-17   30-Aug-17
1143578 Oct 17  13-Oct-17   07-Sep-17
1143578 Oct 17  18-Oct-17   07-Sep-17
1143578 Oct 17  19-Oct-17   07-Sep-17
```

I need to identify all clients who have had at least one transaction per month. I am thinking, based on their first transaction date, calculate how many month they should have had at least one transaction for (Count_month) (eg., if client first transaction is Sept 2017, so from October 2017 to June 2019, the number of month they need to have at least one transaction in is 21). 
And then create another counter to loop through each M_YR (month, year), and add 1 if a unique client had a transaction in a given Month-year (Count_client)...(eg., if client had at least one transaction a month from October 2017 to June 2019, the counter would be 21)

If I compare these two variables (Count_client and Count_month), if Count_client < Count_month then i will know this client did not have at least one transaction per month.

Does this method work? is there an easier way to do this? I feel this is probably not the simplest solution but I am currently out of ideas..

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the number of months between first transaction and present date you can use:

```
compute Months_since_1st = datediff($time, First_Trans, "months").
```

(the $Time expression will use present date in calculation - you can replace that with any other date).

To calculate the number of months that had any transaction:

```
dataset name orig.
* identifying every month/year that had transactions - per client.
dataset declare agg1.
aggregate out=agg1 /break=Cli_ID M_YR /n=n.
dataset activate agg1.
* counting them for each client.
dataset declare agg2.
aggregate out=agg2 /break=Cli_ID /Nmonths_with_transactions=n.
* attaching the results back to original data.
dataset activate orig.
match files /file = * /table = agg2 / by Cli_ID.
```